# Sending a JSON list to Spring controller results in null value

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, fetch

I have a @RestController with an endpoint of method=POST.
I'm sending a JSON of type:

```
{"dataList":[
    {
        "id":5,
        "nickname":"START",
        "percent":0.92,
        "weight":55.33,
        "price":9679.57
    },
    {...},
    {...}
    ]
}
```

from my ReactJs function using the fetch API like this:

```
const response = fetch('http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/my/test', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                dataList: postData
            })
        });
```

On the backend side there's my endpoint action:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "api/my/test")
  public ResponseEntity test(TestListDto dataList) {
    /** NOTE: The endpoint is hit successfuly but the dataList INTERNAL LIST is null**/

    // dataList here is a valid object
    // dataList.getDataList() though is NULL !

    /** some business logic**/

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
  }

public class TestListDto {
  private List<TestDto> dataList; // THIS IS NULL WHEN ENDPOINT IS HIT

  public PaymentListDto(List<TestDto> dataList) {
    super();
    this.dataList = dataList;
  }

  public List<TestDto> getDataList() {
    return dataList;
  }

  public void setDataList(List<TestDto> dataList) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
  }
}

public class TestDto {
  private Long id;
  private String nickname;
  private BigDecimal percent;
  private BigDecimal weight;
  private BigDecimal price;

 // constructor + getters/setters
}
```

I know I have to wrap a list in a Class when using POST but why is my interal data null.
Any help appreciated!

***EDIT***: Problem turned out to be that the request's content-type header is readonly in 'no-cors' mode and cannot be changed to application/json thus the server recognizes the received type as a plain text and not an object.
Fixed it by enabling the endpoint for cross origin requests from my front end server.

Comment: Can you try changing your endpoint like this : `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/noinvoice",consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: @AhmetAmasyalı this returns Error code 415`error: "Unsupported Media Type"
message: "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"`

Comment: Do you have an endpoint that maps `myapp/api/my/test` ? The `fetch` triggers POST on that

Comment: @MasterPo yes, I have explicitly said the endpoint is hit successfully ... It's just the data that is not populated

Comment: But the back end rest controller you given have the following `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/noinvoice")`. That's why I confused. If so the url that  you use in `fetch` should end with `/noinvoice` with your app context prefixed. (`myapp/api/noinvoice`)

Comment: @MasterPo yes, thanks for pointing out! I've changed some cuz its a sensitive information but left one out :)

Comment: @StoyanLupov when you are making the request are you adding the header Content-Type:application/json?

Comment: @AhmetAmasyalı yes, take a look at my fetch call

Comment: Can you try it by adding `@RequestBody` before `TestListDto ` in the API handler method param?. I hope you are sending the data in HTTP POST request body. It will be like...  `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "api/my/test")
  public ResponseEntity test(@RequestBody TestListDto dataList)`

Comment: @MasterPo For some reason my request content-type is "text/plain;charset=UTF-8". I see thats the error but why is that so when I've explicitly set it to application/json in my fetch call

Comment: That seems the issue with the `fetch` method can you try  without using `JSON.stringify`?. Simply set `body:postData`

Comment: @MasterPo yes, that must be the problem indeed. I've tried your suggestion, still getting a request with Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' which is not supported by my endpoint :(

Comment: @MasterPo turns out the content-type header is readonly in 'no-cors' mode and cannot be changed to application json. It's a problem on my end because i need the no cors mode at this moment of development.